# Linux MySQL Permission denied on dynamic mounted drive

Tags: mysql

So I've installed MySQL on my PC (Linux Mint 21).
I mounted the dynamic NTFS Windows drive via ldmtool and tried to launch MySQL:

```bash
$ mysqld --datadir=/media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
```

Got an 13 error (Permission denied).
Then:

```bash
# mysqld --user=root --datadir=/media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
```

Same error...

Full log:

```
2022-12-01T15:43:28.814379Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-12-01T15:43:28.814433Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 6743
2022-12-01T15:43:28.816359Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-12-01T15:43:28.816365Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-12-01T15:43:28.817066Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-12-01T15:43:28.817153Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

I remounted the drive and set the 'ffx' owner (my account) instead of root
But this:

```bash
# mysqld --user=root --datadir=/media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
$ mysqld --user=ffx --datadir=/media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
$ mysqld --datadir=/media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
```

Are also failed.
I remounted the disk to set the 'mysql' owner (so mysql:mysql is owner of WHOLE disk):

```bash
# mount /dev/mapper/... /media/ffx/Data -o uid=mysql -o gid=mysql
```

Now mysql user is owner of whole disk and it still gives that 13 error.
I've tried launch it from the root, ffx and mysql and got failed with the same error.
I also did this after every error:

```bash
# chown -R mysql:mysql /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB
# chown -R mysql:mysql /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB/
# chown -R mysql:mysql /media/ffx/Data/MySQLDB/*
```

but it also failed.

---

No result:

```bash
$ mysqld --install
$ mysqld --initialize
```

Creating an init file with

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourNewPassword';
```

Giving an 777 access to Data;
Giving an 777 access to MySQLDB

---

So question is what should I do and why doesn't it have permissions.